# Why isn't imread in openCV opening some of the images?

Tags: python

The error im getting is

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\harit\Desktop\red.py", line 6, in 
>       cv2.imshow('img',img) error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:304:
>   error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow"

The relevant code is this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\harit\Desktop\images\12.jpg')

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Check those images. Are they well-formed images? It seems a full dimension is missing or, and that depends on opencv, some error like this appears when there is a problem opening a file? You probably should check img before imshow.

Comment: How do i exactly check those images (sorry i am new to openCV and python). I am downloading those images from google. Some of the pictures do open while some of them don't. I have tried opening both the extensions (.png & .jpg).

Comment: Just open them in some image-viewer. And check img before imshow. It might be even wise to check if a file is existing before opening, throwing something useful if not.

Comment: The images do exist and they are opening just fine.

Comment: Existing (i see them in my folder) and existing/loadable from python's perspective are two different things. And yet, you did not check img before imshow. Take your time.

Comment: I have opened similar images through 'imread' from desktop and from my images folder. But still its giving that same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\harit\Desktop\images\12.jpg')
```

to

```
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\harit\Desktop\images\12.jpg')
```

Backslash is an escape character, and the r before the quotes tells python to "ignore" them.

For example:

```
>>> s = 'C:\Users\harit\Desktop\images\12.jpg'
>>> print s
C:\Users\harit\Desktop\images
.jpg
```

This is the wrong path!... with an 'r' in front of the string:

```
>>> s = r'C:\Users\harit\Desktop\images\12.jpg'
>>> print s
C:\Users\harit\Desktop\images\12.jpg
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals for more on raw strings

Comment: Thank you so much! adding 'r' in front of the string really worked!
It works even when double backlash is added instead of adding 'r' in front of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think I kind of understand the problem. Maybe I am wrong with my solution. When I first encountered this problem I thought that open cv only accepts png images instead of jpg however, even after converting the image into an png it still did not make the problem go away. Later on, I tried to rename the name of the image and the new name started with a letter instead of a number and it worked. So, maybe python open cv can't read files with names starting with a number like it cannot accept any variable names that start with numbers. Maybe I am totally wrong, but renaming the image file made the problem go away.

Comment: Hello srijon, welkom to SO community! Please see the accepted answer, the problem results from a not escaped backslash character.